# How to perform transformations on strings in LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have the below query that selects rows from a datatable called dtRows. The dtRows contains 2 columns FieldId and FieldValue and the FieldId contains values as below. When I select the FieldId's I need to strip the first two characters and convert the last character to a different string. For example, 1_3_1 should be 3_FirstName and 1_3_2 should be 3_LastName and 1_3_3 should be 3_MiddleName. Anyone has any suggestions?? Thanks a lot for any ideas!

FieldId Values:

1_1_1
1_1_2
1_1_3
1_2_1
1_2_2
1_2_3
1_3_1
1_3_2
1_3_3

```
var Names = from row in dtRows.AsQueryable()
                   where Convert.ToInt16(row.Field<string>("FieldId").Substring(2)) == prefix
                   select new
                   {
                       fieldId = 
           fieldValue = row.Field<string>("FieldValue")
                   };
```

Comment: What would you do if the last character wasn't in the range 1-3?

Comment: Just switch on fieldId.Last() and put in those values...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I need to maintain all the possible values of the last character and the corresponding names in some variable and then look up the value and retrieve the appropriate name. As phoog suggested, writing a separate function works for me but I was looking if it is possible using Linq. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function to calculate the different strings, and call it:

```
var Names = from row in dtRows.AsQueryable() 
               let id = row.Field<string>("FieldId")
               where Convert.ToInt16(id.Substring(2)) == prefix 
               select new 
               { 
                   fieldId = ConvertString(id),
                   fieldValue = row.Field<string>("FieldValue") 
               };
```

And

```
private string ConvertString(string original)
{
    // implementation left as an exercise
}
```